# ArcGIS is not recognizing my network connections. What do I do?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

So, I've noticed this weird thing when I run ArcMap as administrator.  It shows my folder connections as not connected. The program does not seem to recognize that I have any network drives at all.

Has anyone else ever had this problem, and how do I fix it?

Running 10.1 on Windows 8.1 64 bit

Update:  When I go to make a new folder connection when running as administrator, if I try to click on network locations the program errors out and crashes.

Comment: Did you map them in ArcCatalog? Can you show a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: can you create a new connection manually?

Comment: Check out this post specifically the last response about the paths may helpful. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63171

Comment: @jbchurchill  They were previously mapped in ArcCatalog (without running as administrator). I can still see them in the catalog, however I get the red "x" of disconnect when I try to open them when I run the program as administrator.

Comment: @radouxju I can create a new connection, as long as it is to a folder on my local machine.  So, as an update to my problem, ArcGIS does not recognize that I am connected to a network.

Comment: are the network drive mapped with the same letter in windows explorer ?

Comment: yes they are, and they work just fine unless I am running the program as administrator.

Comment: I see. That post that @ChrisR mentioned indicated that deleting the ArcCatalog template file might work or possibly mapping UNC paths instead of mapped drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installing the software fixed the problem. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem in ArcCatalog 10.5. All the network work drives had a little red cross on them. Turned out that the Icon for ArcCatalog on my desktop was set to run as Administrator (Properties > Shortcut tab > Advanced). When I unticked that all the drives were available again.

Looks like a permission thing or that those drives are not mapped under the Administrator profile?